# Error While running an android app..!

Tags: android

I had developed an android task reminder app. It has no errors but some warnings and that are only due to deprecated methods. When I run my app,it says UNFORTUNATELY APP HAS STOPPED .Can anybody tell me what might be the reason behind that.?
Here is the logcat error that I got:

```
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): Process: com.android.taskreminder, PID: 1038
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.android.taskreminder.OnBootReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.taskreminder.OnBootReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2400)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.taskreminder.OnBootReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2395)
07-14 00:44:05.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     ... 10 more
07-14 00:45:52.640: E/SQLiteLog(1163): (1) near "tablereminders": syntax error
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163): Process: com.android.taskreminder, PID: 1163
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.taskreminder/com.android.taskreminder.ReminderListActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tablereminders": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tablereminders (_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, body text not null,reminder_date_time text not null);
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tablereminders": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tablereminders (_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, body text not null,reminder_date_time text not null);
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at com.android.taskreminder.RemindersDbAdapter$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(RemindersDbAdapter.java:36)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at com.android.taskreminder.RemindersDbAdapter.open(RemindersDbAdapter.java:48)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at com.android.taskreminder.ReminderListActivity.onCreate(ReminderListActivity.java:29)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-14 00:45:52.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1163):     ... 11 more
```

This is the sql code

```
import android.content.ContentValues;    
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class RemindersDbAdapter {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "reminders";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title"; 
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper; 
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("+ KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_BODY + " TEXT NOT NULL,"  + KEY_DATE_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
            private final Context mCtx; 
            public RemindersDbAdapter(Context ctx) { 
            this.mCtx = ctx;
            }

            //nested class
            private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
                DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
                    //main thing happens now
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE); 
                }
                @Override
                public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                int newVersion) { 
                // Not used, but you could upgrade the database with ALTER
                // Scripts
                }
                }

            public RemindersDbAdapter open() throws android.database.SQLException {
                mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
                mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                return this;
                }

            public void close() {
                mDbHelper.close();
                }
            // now we will create a method to create a new reminder
            public long createReminder(String title, String body, String reminderDateTime) { 
                    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
                    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
                    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime);
                    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues); 
                    }

            //delete reminder
            public boolean deleteReminder(long rowId) { 
                return
                mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; 
                }

            //to fetch all reminders
            public Cursor fetchAllReminders() { 
                return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                        KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
                }

            //to fetch a particular reminder
                public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException { 
                Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME},
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
                if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst(); 
                }
                return mCursor;
                }

                //to update existing reminder
                public boolean updateReminder(long rowId, String title, String body, String reminderDateTime) {
                    ContentValues args = new ContentValues(); 
                        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                        args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
                        args.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime);
                        return
                        mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; 
                        }

}
```

Comment: It's caused by an uncaught exception in your code or in Android code that your code calls. Post the logcat output; without that, it's impossible to say much more about the problem.

Comment: Does it halt when you're debugging it?

Comment: can you please post code and logcat ?

Comment: plz post logcat error

Comment: had you gave all the permission in the android manifest file correctly 1st please check that.

Comment: I am using only SQLite databse.Is there any permission needed for using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
near "tablereminders": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tablereminders ...
```

You need whitespace between the keyword `table` and the identifier `reminders`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the logcat, it's pretty clear:

`Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tablereminders": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tablereminders (_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, body text not null,reminder_date_time text not null);`

Your `sql` is invalid.

A little tip: when your app crashes, see the logcat, and locate the last `Caused by`, that's the code/reason that went wrong

Comment: so,what do you think that what problem might be there??

Comment: @RedDevil You should post your `sql`

Comment: You need to print the `sql` to check if your `sql` is valid. `"CREATE TABLE" + DATABASE_TABLE` There is no space in it. That's not right